# Modelising a blackjack table with (functional) Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I would like to make  blackjack game as a way to train my scala skills, and I would like to do so in a functional way, that is only using val attributes.

I have a table, which contains a shoe, which itself contains a list of cards.
Once I deal a card, I have to rebuild a new card list without the card, as it is not mutable, but then I have to rebuild a new shoe with the new list of cards, as the shoe is not mutable. But then I have to rebuild the table with the new shoe, as the table itself is not mutable, etc... 
I feel that I am doing this wrong. What is the table is itself part of a gaming floor which is itself part of a casino, etc .. do I really need to rebuild everything every time a card is dealt, or a bet is made or a player joins or leave ?

Could someone give me some insight on the best way to design this?

Maybe should I store the state of the game in a database instead of in objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have 3 suggestions,

The first is to read the book "[Functional Programming in Scala](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-scala)" it has a chapter that covers functional state which would be invaluable in looking at this.

The second is to look at the [State Monad](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/State.html), it is a monad which wraps a function from S => (A,S) basically a function which takes a current state as input, produces a result and a new state as output.

The last is to look at Functional Lenses, there are several implementations but they allow you to create a copy of an immutable structure with a changed value for a deeply nested attribute. I personally use the [lens implementation in Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/lenses.scala)

One last note, often functional programs are built such that at the outer most layer you deal with mutability and side effects, things like IO, Database interactions, etc. Your idea of storing state in a database would fundamentally mean that you are using mutable state.

Comment: Looking at Lens (quite handy), it seems to me that it is the same problem I have, that is, let's say I create a lens such as `val cardListLens = lens[Casino].cardRoom.table.shoe.cardList;`, when I use it to update the card list, I get a new casino which I use to display data in the front-end, but this means I had to rebuild everything, wouldn't there be performances issues? (maybe not in my case, but in a bigger project)

Comment: Depends a lot on the data structures you use and their characteristics. For example a singly linked list doesn't need to allocate new objects when adding an item to it's head. There is some literature out there around Functional Data Structures, but I don't have any of it handy at the moment

Answer (score 0):

In Clojure (or whatever other (semi-)functional language) I would normally solve this using one atom which is a mutable storage location which itself holds an immutable data structure which represents the entire game state. The game state will usually be modeled using an immutable hashmap with various entries. In Scala that would be a case class probably. There is nothing wrong with having mutation in a functional program, as long as it is isolated in one place and the updates are done atomically with a function that maps the previous to the next state. You'll find the same idea in many of the React implementations, like Redux which represents the entire UI as one data structure. I have no idea if Scala has something like Clojure's atom and if that is considered idiomatic. 
Instead of a mutable reference you can use recursion. Every time a player has played you will enter a new recursion with the new game state.